# Order for sets in the real line

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Consider the sets $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$.

I want to say that $[1,2]$ is greater than $[0,1]$. Is there a set order such that

$$A \geq B \quad \text{if} \quad \inf A \geq \sup B.$$

What is the name of such order?

Comment: There is a notion that if every element of $A$ is greater than every element of $B$, than $A$ is "greater" than $B$ (though I'm not sure if that's the word that's used). This doesn't work for your sets, though, as they overlap at $\{1\}$.

Comment: The week version of that notion would apply. If every element of A is greater or equal than every element of B, A is greater or equal than B. I want to say that A is greater or equal than B, but I would want to refer the reader to the order I am using, so I was looking for the name of such order... Thanks!

Comment: Pages 41-43 of this article seem relevant: http://interval.louisiana.edu/reliable-computing-journal/volume-16/reliable-computing-16-pp-38-72.pdf

Comment: I think I might have heard the term "$A$ _dominates_ $B$" somewhere, but I might be confusing this with something else.

Comment: @columbus8myhw — Sorry, but [domination](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Dominate_(Set_Theory)) refers to the property that there exists an injection from one set into the other.

Answer (score 0):

If a relation is labeled as an "order" then there are two possibilities: it is irreflexive or it is reflexive.

If $A$ is a singleton then $A\geq A$ so the relation is *not* irreflexive.

If $A$ has two distinct elements then $A\not\geq A$ so the relation is *not* reflexive.

Conclusion: we are not dealing with a relation that gets the label "order" in mathematics.

Comment: You can have it be a partial order and irreflexive still, by requiring that all elements of $A$ be strictly greater than $B$ to count

Comment: @Alan You mean by "throwing out the (incomplete) diagonal"? Yes, you have a point there. Let's say that my answer is purely focused on the relation mentioned in the question. Your comment is a welcome side note.

Comment: You say that because the relation is an "order" then it must be either irreflexive or reflexive. Please explain why it cannot be neither, namely, that it cannot be that there are some sets $C$ for which $C \ge C$ **and** there are other sets $D$ such that $D \not\ge D$.

Comment: @chharvey  I am only referring to definitions that I have met. Partial orders are mainly presented (by definition) as reflexive, transitive and  antisymmetric. Linear orders mainly as irreflexive, transitive, asymmetric and comparable. I never engaged orders with non-empty and non-complete diagonal. Also if (pre)orders are looked at as categories then they are always reflexive. I don't exclude though that there is more beyond my scope.

Comment: @chharvey Also I think that caution is needed when it comes to labeling. If conditions are dropped and more things get the name "order" then confusion comes closer.